# AWS EC2 connects to S3 inside VPC without passing throught Internet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

I have an EC2 instance in a AWS VPC public subnet.

If an application running on the instance connects to S3 with a Boto3 client, is the traffic routed inside AWS network even if I don't have a gateway endpoint set in the VPC or it goes throught Internet?

If to keep traffic in AWS network I need a VPC endpoint, then how can I use a gateway VPC endpoint with a Boto3 client?

Comment: Traffic to a public IP address owned by an AWS service in the same region will exit the VPC and route across the AWS network. It will stay within the AWS network without exiting to the 'Internet' (but it still uses Internet routing protocols and public IP addresses). You could try `traceroute` to see where it goes, but it would be difficult to decipher.

Answer (score 2):

> if I don't have a gateway endpoint set in the VPC or it goes throught Internet?

Yes, if you do not have S3 gateway nor S3 interface endpoint, traffic to S3 goes over the internet.

> how can I use a gateway VPC endpoint with a Boto3 client?

You don't have to do anything if you configure S3 gateway or S3 interface endpoint correctly. This will work seamlessly with boto3.

Comment: Thanks Marcin. Is there a way to check that the S3 service is reached by Boto3 client over AWS network? To resolve gateway endpoint and not public endpoint is it necessary that private DNS option is set for the VPC?

Answer (score 0):

Well you can verify yourself from AWS S3 server logs if traffic is coming from VPC endpoint or internet(IGW or NAT). If both are configured on your subnet's route table then VPC endpoint will take precedence over IGW/NAT. Make sure you attach correct IAM role for accessing S3 from your EC2.